# What is "to imagine Diana like that!"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The story is about love potion, a conversation between a seller and a customer:

> "How carefully she will look after you! She will never allow you to be tired, to sit in a draught, to neglect your food. If you are an hour late, she will be terrified. She will think you are killed, or that some siren has caught you."
>
> "I can hardly imagine Diana like that!" cried Alan, overwhelmed with joy.

What is "to imagine Diana like that!" in the text above? 
Thanks..

Comment: Separately, "She will think..." implies events that already would have occurred, so they need to be past tense. "you *were* killed" and "some siren *had* caught you".

Answer (score 3):

*I can hardly imagine Diana like that!* means that the person who's speaking has a hard time imagining or visualising Diana in that capacity or role. To put it simply, they have a hard time believing that it's possible for Diana to be able to do all those things that have just been listed. Consider this example:

> Living on the streets and asking people for money—I just can't imagine myself like that! That's beneath my dignity!

Here, I'm saying that the thought that one day I might find myself living on the streets and asking people for money is unimaginable for me to the point that it even sounds offensive to my senses.

Were you able to follow my explanation?